# How to pass default credentials in Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm developing UWP application using C#.net and it has WCF service with Windows Authentication enabled. I struggling to pass default NetworkCredential after consume a service call using Add service reference option.

Please find below my examinations.

When I pass correct windows authentication credentials, it is working as expected.

```
var service = new ServiceReference.Service1Client();
service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential =new NetworkCredential("pradeep","****");
var test = await service.GetDataAsync(1);
```

but, I wanted pass default network credentials while using my service methis

```
var service = new ServiceReference.Service1Client();
service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
var test = await service.GetDataAsync(1);
```

I also tried below option.

```
service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = (NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

When I pass default credentials. I'm getting below exception.

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate, NTLM'.

I tested same service call with default NetworkCredential in WPF application which is working as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to pass the default credentials for the WCF Windows Authentication in UWP by using the **System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials**, first please make sure that you have added the **Enterprise Authentication** and **Private Networks(Client & Server)** capabilities as following:

[image]

For the **Enterprise Authentication** capability, it is because that Windows domain credentials enable a user to log into remote resources using their credentials, and act as if a user provided their user name and password. The enterprise Authentication special capability is typically used in line-of-business apps that connect to servers within an enterprise.

For the **Private Networks(Client & Server)** capability, it is because that currently in Windows Runtime we can only pass the default credential in the Intranet. For the Internet we have to use the Username and Password as credential.

For more information about the Capabilities, please check:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx .

After that please try to use your **Computer name** or **Fully Qualified Computer name** instead of the IP address for your WCF Services like this: http://YourComputerName:YourPortNumber/Service1.svc.

At last please use another computer as client to test the WCF Windows Authentication in UWP with the **System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials**, then it should work fine.

Thanks.