# Surface Hub - Using Device Account for Windows Authentication in the UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, surface-hub

Is there any way to use the current device account on the Surface Hub as credentials to authenticate in remote services hosted on IIS that use Windows authentication in the UWP app?

Currently we're using the default credentials supported by System.Net.HttpClient, and it works fine on the desktop, but the Hub sends wrong credentials and it results in 401 Unauthorized response.

Both the Hub and the service are joined to the AD Domain.

Comment: Reading between the lines, you want to use a web app, and you want to use the currenty logged in credentials to authenticate. What credentials does your web app think you are using? Have you configured IIS correctly to not use anonymous authentication?

Comment: The services are configured OK - as I said, on desktop it works correctly.


To simplify my problem - I need any way whatsoever in the UWP installed on Surface Hub to access the Device Account data (even the username would suffice)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have added the **Enterprise Authentication** and **Private Networks(Client & Server) capabilities** in your app manifest.

Besides, you can also refer this similar thread:

[How to pass default credentials in Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126305/how-to-pass-default-credentials-in-windows-authentication/36197993#36197993)

Comment: Yeah, I saw all that - and on desktop it works perfectly. The question is how to implement that on Surface Hub.