# UWP NTLM Authentication with Windows default credentials

Tags: windows, authentication, uwp, ntlm

Could you clarify, is there "ready to go" API for UWP? I have not found any work example with Windows Default Creadentials. All existing example with User's login and password.

Comment: I did not understand what you're doing. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to add more information in your post.

Comment: Xavier Xie, thank you for comment. Sorry, I will add some more information.In a Windows network, NT LAN Manager (NTLM) is a suite of Microsoft security protocols that provides authentication, integrity, and confidentiality to users. NTLM is the successor to the authentication protocol in Microsoft LAN Manager (LANMAN), an older Microsoft product. And Default Credentials [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials?view=netframework-4.7.2] And together all these stuff have to work on the UWP

Comment: In theory this code should work, but its not.
`HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
UseDefaultCredentials = true,
...
};
..
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);`
MS do not provide working example (at least I have not found). I have no idea in which direction I have to go. 
Is there API, dll etc from MS? Can I use third party libraries? Maybe some other?

Comment: Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126305/how-to-pass-default-credentials-in-windows-authentication/36197993#36197993) and try to enable the **Enterprise Authentication** capability, **Private Networks(Client & Server)** capability.

Comment: Thank you Xavier Xie. I sow it earlier. Unfortunately it does not work in my case.

Comment: If you use the above code in a classic desktop application, did it work?

Comment: The idea to check is good. Its diffucult to cut objects from a big project to check. Will try. If you have any other tips, you are welcome.